# Docker build of Apache Superset fails with "The command '/bin/sh -c npm run ${BUILD_CMD}' returned a non-zero code: 1"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-superset

I am trying to build a Docker image for **Apache Superset** by cloning the official GitHub repository using the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git
```

After that, I attempt to run the docker build command:

```
docker build -t superset:1.0.0 .
```

However, during the build process, I encounter an error message that says:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run ${BUILD_CMD}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

[image]

Due to this error, the Docker image is *not successfully built*. I have searched for solutions but haven't been able to find a resolution. I suspect it might be related to npm or other dependencies, but I am not sure.

I am running the build on a **Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS** with **Docker version 20.10.21**.

Can someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and include a [mcve]?  You need to include the actual source code and the complete error message in the question itself.  The "returned a non-zero code" message doesn't mean anything more than "it didn't work".

Comment: I mentioned the actual source code at the beginning "git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git".

Comment: I am having the same issue, the error is really not helpful. Did you manage to solve this?